# Finding an eigenvalue and eigenfunction of $y''+\lambda y = 0$, $y(-2)=0$, $y'(2)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the title says, how does one find an eigenvalue and eigenfunction of $y'' + \lambda y = 0$ when $y(-2)=0$, $y'(2)=0$? I eliminated the case of $\lambda$ being zero and negative, but I am stuck with the positive lambda.

I got $y(-2)=c_1\cos(-2\lambda)+c_2\sin(-2\lambda) = c_1\cos(2\lambda)-c_2\sin(2\lambda) = 0$ and $y'(2) = \lambda(-c_1\sin2\lambda+c_2\cos 2\lambda) = 0$

but then I am stuck here.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\sqrt{\lambda}$?

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of $y''+\lambda y=0$, for $\lambda>0$, is
$$
y(x)=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\,x)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\,x),
$$
or equivalently
$$
y(x)=c_1\cos\big(\sqrt{\lambda}\,(x-2)\big)+c_2\sin\big(\sqrt{\lambda}\,(x-2)\big),
$$
If $y(-2)=y(2)=0$, then $c_1=0$, and $\,\,\sin(4\sqrt{\lambda})=0$. Thus
$$
4\sqrt{\lambda}=k\pi,\quad k\in\mathbb N,
$$
or
$$
\lambda=\frac{k^2\pi^2}{16}, \quad k\in\mathbb N,
$$
with corresponding eigenfunctions $u_k(x)=\sin \big(\frac{1}{4}k\pi (x-2)\big)$.

Comment: The question specifies $y'(2) = 0$, not $y(2) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

you get that $ \frac{c1}{c2}=\frac{c2}{c1} $ from your equation

so the eiganvalues are given by the solution of the equations

$ -1=tan(2\lambda) $

$ 1=tan(2\lambda) $

Comment: This doesn't completely answer OP's question. Where is the eigenfunction? (HINT: If x (t) is your eigenfunction then it consists of basically the general solution terms multiplied by the respective eigenvector .